# How to send data from a chrome extension to a react app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am very new to chrome extensions and react. An overview of what I am doing is pretty straight forward. I have a chrome extension which takes a screenshot of the activeTab and I want to send that screenshot from the extension to my react app.

From what I understand, I need to dispatch an event from the extension and have the react app listen to it. I have an event listener in the index.html of my react app to listen to events that are dispatched by the extension. I have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

Here's what I have so far:

**Chrome extension**

**popup.js**

```
let tabImage = document.getElementById('tabImage');
let capturedImage = null;

tabImage.onclick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, (image) => {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('csEvent', { data: image })) // send image to react app
        viewScreenshot(image);
    });
}


//Create a new window in the browser with the captured image
viewScreenshot = (capturedImage) => {
    const b64 = capturedImage;
    const contentType = 'image/jpeg';

    const byteCharacters = atob(b64.substr(`data:${contentType};base64,`.length));
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 1024) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 1024);

        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.open(blobUrl, '_blank');
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <button id="tabImage">Get a screenshot!</button>
    <script src='popup.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**reactJS app**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>Shots</title>


</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="qa_films" src="./demo_course_classic_player_html5-flash-AMP/story.html"
    style="position:absolute ;top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:90%; border:none; margin:0 auto; padding:0; z-index: 0; overflow:hidden; "></iframe>

  <div id="screenshot"></div>


</body>

<script>
  document.body.addEventListener('csEvent', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  })
</script>

</html>
```

I would like to know which part I am doing it wrong or is there a better way of implementing what I'm trying to achieve. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The popup is a separate page with its own `window` and `document` so instead of DOM events you need to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage as shown in [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) and [sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) documentation. Also note, the popup's script runs only when the popup is shown so maybe you'd want to declare a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) instead.

Comment: I see, so I set up a background.js. How would I pass a message from inside a react component?

Comment: IF you want to pass the information from one Component to the other you should use props, but if you have too many files in which the information is required then go for **context** API or **Redux**